# Remove in foreach just before break

Tags: c#, foreach

I know there are lots of ways to do it much better but I've seen it in existing code and now I'm wondering whether or not this could have any negative side effects. Please note the break right after Remove. Therefore I don't care about the iterator in general, however, I do care about unexpected behavior (-> potential exceptions).

```
foreach (var item in items)
{
    //do stuff
    if (item.IsSomething)
    {
        items.Remove(item); //is this safe???
        break;
    }
}
```

Could it also be possible the compiler optimizes something in a way I don't expect?

Comment: It's fine to do that if you don't continue the enumeration.

Comment: it's a good question which you could answer by just running your code once. tell us how it behaves

Comment: It's been in use for quite some time. So it works in my case. I just want to make sure it's a safe and valid pattern (I won't use it in the future though).

Comment: if there wasn't a `break;` it wouldn't work (since the enumerator of `items` has changed). What unexpected behavior are you expecting here? What would motivate a possible UB? This looks very well formed to me.

Comment: An internal caught exception for example. That would probably have a performance impact.

Comment: @Dunken: You can be sure that the framework will not catch exceptions silently as normal behaviour. All the more in a basic construct that is performance critical like a `foreach`-loop.

Comment: @Tim Schmelter: +1, thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The compiler generates a call to `Dispose()` on the enumerator that is executed in a `finally` block, but that shouldn't be a problem. If you `break` right after removing the item, nothing bad should happen, since you don't use the enumerator anymore.

If you want to do it a different way though (for style reasons or whatever), you could do this:

```
var item = items.FirstOrDefault(i => i.IsSomething);
if (item != null) {
    items.Remove(item);
}
```

It's also a bit shorter :) (I am assuming here you are using a reference or nullable type in your collection).

Comment: +1, But whats wrong with this code if `items` is a `List` of `struct`?

Comment: @IlyaIvanov structs would require a different approach since the default value of a struct is still a valid instance of this struct, just with all fields initialized to their default values (structs cannot be `null`). For example, `int` is defined as a struct/value type, and its default value is 0 (not `null`), which is still a valid number.

Comment: @IlyaIvanov: Correct, for structs you could use `Where`+`Any`+`First`: `var itemsWithSomething = items.Where(i => i.IsSomething);
            bool hasSomething = itemsWithSomething.Any();`

Comment: @TimSchmelter I thought of adding something similar first, but depending of the implementation of these extension methods for the used collection type, calls to `Where`, `Any` and `First` (for specifying the item to remove) might iterate the collection more than once, so the approach in the original question might be better then. the performance difference probably does not matter, but who knows what the collection does internally.

Comment: @Botz3000 @TimSchmelter Got it. I thought `item != null` wont compile if `item` is `struct`, but I was wrong. Thanks for clarification.

Comment: @IlyaIvanov: `item!=null` will compile but the result will be incorrect since `FirstOrDefault` will never return null if `Item` is a struct even if there are no items with `i.IsSomething=true`.

Comment: @Botz3000: Does it really matter in Linq-To-Objects? I think you won't measure a difference in most cases since `Any` and `First` will break as soon as one with `IsSomething` was found and a simple boolean check is not expensive. Readability first.

Comment: @TimSchmelter Yes, you're right. In most cases it really doesn't matter and readability and correctness should come first.  
And i haven't yet come across that collection type where it would matter (the one that hits a database on the other end of the world on each iteration without caching).

Answer (score 2):

The compiler and everything else which is in touch with your application guarantees SC-DRF (sequential consistency for data-race-free programs), so you won't see the difference between the program you wrote and the program which is executed (which is anything but the same). Assuming `items` is not shared between multiple threads this is completely safe to write and has no unexpected behaviors others than if you would call `Remove` outside the loop.

Answer (score 1):

You can't change the list while iterating within foreach.

The underlying collection cannot be modified while it's being enumerated. A standard approach is to keep the items to remove in second list , and then after Items has been enumerated, then remove each item from Items.

Comment: I do change the list while iterating. The example I gave might be bad practice but it works.

Answer (score -1):

then u can do this -- its more efficient when dealing with large lists (Assuming entity framework)

```
var reducedList = items.where(a=>a.IsSomething).toList();
foreach(var item in reducedList)
{
    reducedList.Remove(item);
}
```

this reduces the `foreach` loop iterations

Comment: Seems odd to use a loop and break after the first iteration.

Comment: Well the problem is you are still iterating over an List while deleting items from it. This doesn't solve a thing. (You even have now 2 loops)

Comment: @all yes it is please ignore